# codeigniter set_select can't get data from session

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to post a value from a title data which came from my session. other input fields are working except select, radio button, checkbox function is not showing the value.

Controller

```
function index(){

    $data = $this->get_data_from_session();
    $this->load->view('edit_profile', $data);
}

function get_data_from_post(){
    $data['title']          = $this->input->post('title', TRUE);
    $data['firstname']      = ucwords(strtolower($this->input->post('firstname', TRUE)));
    return $data;
}

function get_data_from_session(){
    $data['title'] = $this->session->userdata('title');
    $data['firstname'] = $this->session->userdata('firstname');
    return $data;
}

function update(){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('firstname', 'First Name', 'trim|required|min_length[2]|xss_clean');
    if ($this->form_validation->run($this) == FALSE){
        $data = $this->get_data_from_post();
        $this->load->view('edit_profile',$data);
    }else{
        //update db         
    }
}
```

View File (edit_profile.php)

```
<?php echo form_open('update'); ?>
<select name="title" class="form-control">
   <option value="" <?php echo set_select('title', ''); ?> >Title</option>
   <option value="Dr" <?php echo set_select('title', 'Dr'); ?> >Dr</option>
   <option value="Mr" <?php echo set_select('title', 'Mr'); ?> >Mr</option>
   <option value="Mrs" <?php echo set_select('title', 'Mrs'); ?> >Mrs</option>
   <option value="Ms" <?php echo set_select('title', 'Ms'); ?> >Ms</option>
</select>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="* First Name" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $firstname; ?>" autofocus autocomplete="off">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">UPDATE INFORMATION</button>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

firstname is showing the value but the title is not.
Can anybody help me with this problem? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you can do this.(as you are echoing the variable for firstname above)

```
<?php echo form_open('update'); ?>
<select name="title" class="form-control">
   <option value="" <?php echo  $title=='' ? 'selected="selected"' : '';?> >Title</option>
   <option value="Dr" <?php echo $title=='Dr' ? 'selected="selected"' : '';?> >Dr</option>
   <option value="Mr" <?php echo $title=='Mr' ? 'selected="selected"' : '';?> >Mr</option>
   <option value="Mrs" <?php echo $title=='Mrs' ? 'selected="selected"' : '';?> >Mrs</option>
   <option value="Ms" <?php echo $title=='Ms' ? 'selected="selected"' : '';?> >Ms</option>
</select>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="* First Name" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $firstname; ?>" autofocus autocomplete="off">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">UPDATE INFORMATION</button>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: wow this is great! I'll take this for my other pages. Thanks a lot sir.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( ! function_exists('set_select'))
{
function set_select($field = '', $value = '', $default = FALSE)
{
    $OBJ =& _get_validation_object();

    if ($OBJ === FALSE)
    {
        if ( ! isset($_POST[$field]))
        {
            if (count($_POST) === 0 AND $default == TRUE)
            {
                return ' selected="selected"';
            }
            return '';
        }

        $field = $_POST[$field];

        if (is_array($field))
        {
            if ( ! in_array($value, $field))
            {
                return '';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (($field == '' OR $value == '') OR ($field != $value))
            {
                return '';
            }
        }

        return ' selected="selected"';
    }

    return $OBJ->set_select($field, $value, $default);
}
}
```

This is the CI set_select function which expects $field to be supplied with post method. and here you aren't, you are supplying through session.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sir I updated my code. somehow that's how my code looks like. anyway, I just used the session to post the data from my DB that store to session.

Answer (score 0):

First name is showing beause you are using `value="<?php echo $firstname; ?>"` instead of `value="<?php echo set_value('firstname'); ?>"` .Set_value for input fields is directly from post and is equivalent to set_select (of select field). Now check whether firstname appears using set_value().

Comment: it didn't appear anymore.

Comment: Thank you for your concern sir :) I'm now thinking about that set_value. may I know sir what is the difference between echoing the variable and set_value? I'm Newbie sorry :)

Comment: you will get post variable and echo it to the value of the field which requires `$data['firstname']      = ucwords(strtolower($this->input->post('firstname', TRUE)));` which is implicitly caught by set_value() function.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved :)
i just include some line of codes

```
<option value="Mr" <?php echo set_select('title', 'Mr', ($title == 'Mr')); ?> >Mr</option>
<option value="Mrs" <?php echo set_select('title', 'Mrs', ($title == 'Mrs')); ?> >Mrs</option>
```

this is what I include inside the set_select and it's also work with radio button.

```
, ($title == 'Mr')
```